Dayjs wrong timezone conversion
// DATE = 2024-06-13T23:59:59+05:00
  let dateTime = dayjs(date, format, locale, strict);

  // +05 UTC OFFSET
  dateTime = dateTime.utcOffset(300);

  console.log('1 - ', dateTime.format());
  // 2024-06-13T23:59:59+05:00 | OK

  // -03 UTC OFFSET
  dateTime = dateTime.utcOffset(-180);

  console.log('2 - ', dateTime.format());
  // 2024-06-13T07:59:59-03:00 | WRONG! SHOULD BE 15:59:59-03:00

Idk why dayjs is converting 2024-06-13T23:59:59+05:00 to 2024-06-13T07:59:59-03:00

This appears to be a bug, and it was already reported here:
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/2427
